# Sudden Scaling of Simple Node.js App

Tags: node.js, scalability

My website is written in Node.js, has no database or external dependencies, but does have lot of large media files (images and some video) totalling some 2gb. The structure of the website is drawn from a couple of simple JSON files.

My problem is drastic and sudden scaling. Traffic to my site is usually easily handled by any small VPS instance, but occasionally traffic can get to hundreds of times it normal level for short periods. My problem is how to scale quickly, without downtime, and automatically. I know there are issues with autoscaling, but perhaps lacking a database will negate some of that.

What sort of scaling issues and options should I be looking at?

(For context, I am currently using a Digital Ocean VPS, but I can't find a clean way to scale it with no downtime. I am not wedded to my provider.)

Comment: Do you know the high-volume traffic will come? Do you know how long it will last?

Comment: No, given that it happens when one of my pictures generates a lot of interest on social networks/reddit, etc. It's fairly unpredictable, although usually large peaks will last a couple of days.

Comment: Is the problem that the server cannot handle enough concurrent requests, or that each request is taking too long to respond? Do you write your web server that handles these requests?

Comment: The problem is the number of requests, the page serving time is relatively quick. Yes, I write my web serving app.

Answer (score 3):

Scalability is important, but scaling when you *need* to is also important. We all do not have the scaling needs of Facebook or Twitter : ) This *might* just be a case of resource management.

**Test the problem**

Without a database and using NodeJS, some of the strengths of node are its number of concurrent connections. For simple io load, it would seem you have picked a good choice of framework. And, since your problem set is a particular resource being bombarded, run some load testing on your server. Popular and free tools include:

- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html)
- [httperf](https://code.google.com/p/httperf/)
- [OpenLoad](http://openwebload.sourceforge.net/)

And there are pay service like [NeoLoad](http://www.neotys.com/performance-load-testing-tools.html), [LoadImpact](http://loadimpact.com/) (which is free at small levels), forecastweb, E-Load, etc..

**With those results, Determine the Cause**

Is it the size of the file being served? Is it the number of concurrent requests? What resources are being used, or maxed out, during a slowdown (ram, ports, file system, some other IO, CPU, bandwidth, etc...)?

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333593/scalability-issue-when-using-outgoing-asynchronous-web-requests-on-iis-7-5), which defines a few concepts for server load. To implement a solution, you will need to determine the cause of the slowdown. Is it: 1)Some queues fill up? 2)Problem with TCP Connections and Ports? 3) Too slow allocation of resources? That will help shape your solution.

**Plan for scaling.**

The type of scaling needed for your project may only be the portion needed for another. If you know the root cause in this case, it will increase your options.

Is the problem bandwidth? Perhaps using your web server as a router to multiple cloud instances of file serving would effectively increase the bandwidth your users see. Even just storing your files on a larger cloud that can guarantee the bandwidth you may need.

Is the problem CPU, RAM, etc? You may need multiple instances of the same web app (or an increased allotment for your VFS). This is the "Elastic" portion of Amazon's Elastic Cloud Computing (EC2), and other models like it. Create a "golden image" and duplicate when you see traffic start spiking, using built-in monitoring tools, turning it off when the rush is done. Can be programatic or simply manual.

Is the problem concurrent requests? The bottleneck should not be NodeJS, up to 1000's of concurrent requests anyway. Perhaps just check your implementation to ensure there is not a slowdown of the single node thread. Maybe [node clustering](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or some [worker threads](https://npmjs.org/package/worker-farm) would alleviate the bottleneck enough for your purposes.

**Last Note**: For serving static files I've heard [nginx](http://nginx.com/) or even [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a little more well-suited than NodeJS. Depending on your web app's complexity, you might be able to switch or benchmark fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is reading this rather specific question years later, I have gained some perspective on it. As Clay says, the ultimate answer is to spin up more servers, either manually or programatically based on load.

However, in my case that would be massive overkill - I'm not running Twitter. The problem was a relatively simple mistake in architecture. My app was reading the JSON data files from disk with every page request, and the disk I/O was getting saturated. I changed to loading the data files into memory on startup, and reloading them when they change using fs.watch().

My modest VPS can now easily handle the sorts of traffic that would previously crash it. I've never seen traffic that would make me want to up-size it.

Comment: Big thanks for writing about your solution. A reminder for any scaling: find the bottleneck first.
In case anyone reads this 3 more years later: you can use separate server like apache or nginx for serving static - it works much faster then untuned nodejs afaik.